# I would like to receive alert when web visitor takes screen shot from computer or mobile device. I don't need the contents of the screenshot

Tags: logging, screenshot, analytics

I want to be able to receive an alert when web visitors use my website and take screenshot. I don't need to see what they took screenshot of. I just want to log that action... Is this possible? If so can I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot track the screenshot itself as its not a browser/DOM event rather a windows/OS event . You could track the copy/paste/cut event however its very limited in which elements it covers . Here is a list http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html
You can also track the keypress event,by tracking which keys they press and wait for the CTRL+PrtScrn if they use the printscreen feature built in to the keyboard, however if they use a separate tool you are out of luck